# How to find the gap of log sequence applied in Primary and Standby instance?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-rac, dataguard

How to find log apply gap from the primary database which has more than one standby instance on a RAC environment? Right now I am using the below query but it gives me incorrect results.

`select sequenceInPrimary, sequenceSynchedInStandBy, sequenceInPrimary-sequenceSynchedInStandBy as  logApplyGap from (select max(sequence#) sequenceInPrimary from v$archived_log) ,(select max(sequence#) sequenceSynchedInStandBy from v$archived_log where applied='YES')`

Answer (score 0):

## I run this query to my dataguard(19c), the results correct.
select sequenceInPrimary, sequenceSynchedInStandBy, sequenceInPrimary-sequenceSynchedInStandBy as  logApplyGap
from (select max(sequence#) sequenceInPrimary from v$archived_log) ,(select max(sequence#) sequenceSynchedInStandBy
from v$archived_log where applied='YES')

399 398 1

Comment: Is your dataguard in RAC environment?

Comment: no, they are not rac. data guard are on two different vm hosts.

Comment: sorry, I do not have rac environment, I am assume, they should similar only thing difference is thread#

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select STATUS, GAP_STATUS,dest_id from V$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS order by dest_id;
```

Comment: Please explain what this query does.